# In php, passing only the checked in checkbox items to the next page from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm kind of new to php and while coding this i got stuck in the middle please help me,

Basically, i'm retrieving images from my database through while loop, with that i'm adding a checkbox to display just below the retrieved images. Now when i check the required images i want, only the checked in data has to be passed onto the next page. Please have a look at my code:

```
include('config.php');
echo '<center><form name="myform" action="page.php" method="POST">';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div id="imagelist">';
echo '<p><img width="50px" src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
echo '<input name="data" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['location'].'">';
echo '</div>';
}
echo'<input type="submit" class="input-submit" value="Create Page"/>';
```

Comment: That's standard HTTP. Checkboxes in a form which are UNCHECKED at the time the form is submitted, are NOT submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like

```
 echo '<input name="data[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['location'].'">';

var_dump($_POST['data']);


 if(isset($_POST['data'])){
     foreach($_POST['data'] as $k=>$data){
          echo $data;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the output is an array. I'm using foreach to show the data clearly but my code is not working. Any guess why?   $data = var_dump($_POST['data']);
foreach($data as $dataOne){
echo $data;
}

Comment: Try this, `$data = $_POST['data']; foreach($data as $dataOne){ echo $data; } `

Comment: Yes, i removed the var_dump on the other page & i got my output. $data = $_POST['data'];
foreach($data as $dataOne){
echo $dataOne.'<br>'; 
}  Thanks a lot bro :)